# Was Wahshi Wahshi ibn Harb's real name?

Tags: islam, names, islamic-history

I was reading the Wikipedia article for [Wahshi ibn Harb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wahshi_ibn_Harb).

> Wahshi ibn Harb ("The Savage, Son of War"), also known as Abu Dusmah was a former slave of Jubayr ibn Mut'im before becoming a freedman and a Sahabi (companion of the Islamic prophet Muhammad).

Wahshi means savage in Arabic. I don't know if that was his real name. Abu Dusmah was his [Kunya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunya_(Arabic)); Abu means father; so it's likely he had a son called Dusmah.

Some people also say he was a relative of [Abu Sufyan ibn Harb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Sufyan_ibn_Harb), but I think it's not correct. Because Wahshi was an Abyssinian slave while Abu Sufyan was a rich Arab. Of course, some people also say that Abu Sufyan made Wahshi his brother by appointing his father's name to him (ibn Harb) as a thanksgiving for the killing of [Hamza ibn Abd al-Muttalib](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamza_ibn_Abd_al-Muttalib).

On the other hand, some people say Wahshi wasn't his real name. It was just for labeling him as a low-class slave.

Is there any source that proves it as his real name or suggest another name as his real name?

Comment: Names are just words we humans make up to help differentiate one person from another. What would make one name more "real" than another?

Comment: Real name is the official name. The name that parents choose for their baby. The name that is on your ID card. The name that people write on financial contracts. I have a nickname too. But that's not my real name.

Comment: They didn't have any kind of ID cards or written birth records back then. Arguably, *every* name was a "nickname".

Comment: You forgot the parents' choice. The name that parents choose is the official name, whether today or 1000 years ago. I don't think parents name their children savage! Also you forgot contracts too. People write their official names on contracts, whether today or 1000 years ago.

Comment: Nicknames were kunyas. They came after the official names. For example, Abu al-Hasan was the kunya of the eighth Shiite Imam, while his official name was Ali ibn Musa.

Comment: Let's talk about that "official name". "ibn" is Arabic for "son of". Early Arabic society (like Medieval European society) didn't really use patronyms. Rather they used differentiators. If everyone knew your father, then when needing to say which "Ali" you are, they used "Ali ibn {Fathersname}". However, if he wasn't well-known where you were because you were, say an immigrant from Baghdad, they might instead use "al Bagdhadi" ("the Bagdhadian"). That's a completely context-specific part of a person's name, bestowed by others, not your own family. Only much later did those become patronyms.

Comment: Okay, dump the ibn x part. Ali was his official name.

Comment: But still doubtful about Wahshi.

Comment: Of course not all al-X are kunyas. For example, Abd al-Muttalib was the first name of Muhammad's grandfather.